# Get response while ajax request is being executed

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a question on which if it is even possible and if so, I would please like to know how!

I am executing an ajax request to some url using POST. With the request I send data which contains an array.

On the url I request I want to loop through the array of data and while looping through that array I want to give some feedback on my screen like I am now in key-value 1 of 50 from that array.

Is that possible? I don't want a 'static' loader as feedback but dynamic content from the processed data on my screen. Can someone help me out?

Kind regards,

Pim

Comment: You're going to want to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets)

Comment: did you get a chance to look at https://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Mmhh I've been reading this whole evening about websockets and I do get the idea of it. It seems to be the best solution. Only thing I don't see is how is the server sending data back? What or how can I trigger that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want one request and multiple response.. right? As dave said, solution is to use websockets.

Or 
you can spawn an asynchronous process at server side and have an API/service to check the status of that process. And keep polling that service from the UI

Comment: Websockets are indeed the right solution but due to some time/project management issues I have choosen for another solution